# Purchasing from an NFT collection built on Ethereum with Ethereum based token

Tags: ethereum, solidity

As the title says ... Is it possible to purchase an Ethereum based NFT using a custom Ethereum token?

So let's say I have an NFT contract, all the metadata and images on an ipfs provider ... can I sell the NFTs using my own token?

I plan on displaying the NFTs on a website that will act as a marketplace for specific collections only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your own marketplace, you can definitely do this as you are the one defining the settlement currencies. Superrare settles with RARE tokens as well, not just ETH.

Comment: Ok. Thank you ... So the contract that mints the nfts would have to have a transfer function that gets called after the payment is done. Correct?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Jaca There are multiple ways to do it. If the minting contract is the exchange contract as well, then yes. Opensea has a similar way of doing it. 

A more "proper" way of doing it, would be to create a "marketplace" contract where it would handle all the exchange stuff regardless of the minting. But more complicated. An example is foundation.

Comment: Foundation? Can you give me a link?